# WooCommerce - get product sub categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to get just the sub-categories of a specific category I've created, called *collections* and display them in a `WP_Query` however I can't seem to get just the categories it's marked to show in. I can successfully return all of the categories, just not the specific category it's set to show in.

**What I've tried**

I've tried using `get_terms` in conjunction with `product_cat` taxonomy to no avail and `get_categories` too. I get all of the categories returned, rather than just the ones the product are marked to show in. I've tried pretty much every other method of getting the categories but still to no avail.

**The `WP_Query`**

```
   <ul class="product-slider">
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'product_cat'              => 'sustainable',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => '12'
    );

    $sustain = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($sustain->have_posts()) : while ($sustain->have_posts()) : $sustain->the_post();

        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'product-slider-img' );

        ?>

        <div class="single-product">
            <div class="test">
                <div class="product__image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="product__meta">
                    <div class="product__name">
                        <?php

                        echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id()) ?>


                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__subtitle">
                        <?php echo $product->name; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product__price">
                        £<?php echo $product->price; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="product__link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php

    endwhile; endif;

    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`product_cat` is a custom taxonomy, and you can't just replace the normal `category` parameter with the name of the custom taxonomy. Have a look at the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and you'll see that there is a whole `tax_query` parameter for this use.

In your example, you should replace `'product_cat' => 'sustainable',` with something like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        ),
    ),
```

Note: this is the theory, I can't provide a tested example as I'm not at my desk right now.